# ReactJS Error: TypeError: Class constructor Home cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intentando hacer un proyecto en JavaScript utilizando React. Todo me funciona correctamente hasta que añado este trozo de códio: una nueva clase llamada Home.js.

```
import React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
    return(
      <p>Hola mundo!</p>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Y el error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: Class constructor Home cannot be invoked without 'new'
resolveToLocation
/.../ReactJS/modules/utils/locationUtils.js:4
  1 | import { createLocation } from "history";
  2 | 
  3 | export const resolveToLocation = (to, currentLocation) =>
> 4 |   typeof to === "function" ? to(currentLocation) : to;
  5 | 
  6 | export const normalizeToLocation = (to, currentLocation) => {
  7 |   return typeof to === "string"
```

He estado mirando en Internet, pero no encuentro ninguna solución que me valga.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una clase Home:

```
class Home {
  ...
}
```

y tienes esta función:

```
export const resolveToLocation = (to, currentLocation) =>
  typeof to === "function" ? to(currentLocation) : to;
```

Y en algún sitio se está llamando así:

```
resolveToLocation(Home);
```

Provocando el error que ves, porque las clases en Javascript no son más que "sugar sintax" y tu función `resolveToLocation` no puedes distinguir entre una clase y una función:

```js
class Home {
  constructor() {}
}
function Home2 () {}

//una clase es una función, realmente
console.log('Home:',typeof Home);
console.log('Home:', Home.prototype);
//pero no puede llamarse sin poner new delante:
try {
  new Home(); //esto funciona
  Home(); //esto da un error
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}

//y cualquier función puede ser una clase
console.log('Home2:',typeof Home2);
console.log('Home2:',Home2.prototype);
let aux = new Home2;
console.log(aux instanceof Home2);
```

Comment: ¿Valdría entonces con añadir un constructor? Creo que no acabo de comprender cuál es el problema

Comment: Parece que no me vale con añadir un constructor a la clase Home. No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal

Comment: No, el problema es que Home es una clase. No puedes llamar al constructor de una clase como si fuera una función. He editado la respuesta para añadir más detalles